# Jquery scrollTop only gets height offset on second click?

Tags: jquery, position, offset, scrolltop

I have a page that scrolls to a point based on what menu item is selected. When the page scrolls the menu stays with the page. The problem is the fixed menu hovers over part of the section I need the user to see.

I'm having jquery get the height of the menu and subtrack that from the scrollTop position. However, the height is not being applied on the first click, only clicks after the first.

So, if the scrollTop position is 1442 and the menu is 42 high it first scrolls to 1442. If I click it again it goes to 1400. It should do this (1442-42) calculation on the first click. I checked and the variable that stores the hight is being set each time but only gets applied after the first click:

```
$('#page-nav li').click(function(){
    var selectedPageMenu = $(this).index();
    var pageMenuHeight = $('#page-nav').height();
    var topPos = $('.about-section:eq('+selectedPageMenu+')').position().top - pageMenuHeight;
    $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop: topPos},1000);
});
```

Comment: Can you add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Answer is like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693868/bootstrap-scrollspy-only-gets-height-offset-on-second-click/27695369#27695369