# Bootstrap scrollspy only gets height offset on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a page with bootstrap 3.2.1 and use scrollspy in this page. In the first click on menu doesn't work offset height for scroll page, But after the second click works offset height.

This code work in browsers! but when click title 2 (or title 3 or title 4) for first time the page should be scroll on Title 2 (or Title 3 or Title 4).

```
offsetHeight value = 120;
```

[see Live demo](http://totaldesign.ir/demo/)

[see jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alihesari/4t92zf8p/)

Comment: Works for me (Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0)

Comment: @Sukima yes, this code work in browsers! but when click title 2 (or title 3 or title 4) for first time the page should be scroll on Title 2 (or Title 3 or Title 4). I edit jsfiddle demo. see demo: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alihesari/4t92zf8p/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That because you set the navbar to fixed on scroll down (after y > 90). So you need to *discount* the height of the navbar when it's fixed.

You need a dynamic value, based on your code, a way to do this is using a function with the same parameters. The height of the navbar is 30px so you need to add it.

```
function offsetHeight() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 90) {
    return 120;
  }
  else {
    return 150;
  }
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4336541o/)

Comment: I think I forgot to count the border, maybe add 2px to get the perfect result.