# jQuery scrollTo works correctly only after second click

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I have multiple scrollTo's on a page. The problem is that it is a little off the mark on the first click but correct after subsequent clicks. What can I do to correct this. My code looks like below?:

```
var newHash;

$(".nav-right li a").on('click', function(event) {

    newHash =   $(this).attr("id");

   if (this.hash !== "") {


      // Store hash
     hash = $("h2" + "#" + $(this).attr("id"));
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - $("#header.swag-style").height(),
      }, 800, function(){
         return false;

       window.location.hash = newHash;

      });
    } // End if

  });
```

You can see the problem when you click on the top-nav on the page below:

[>> scrollTo Error](http://cf.rcgc.edu/rowanchoice/index.html#scrollMerge4)

I have tried the solution suggested below to no avail.

[>> stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27693868/bootstrap-scrollspy-only-gets-height-offset-on-second-click/27695369#27695369)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I had the block of code below which adds the `class` `.swag-style`

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {

                   $('#header').addClass('swag-style');

                } else {
                   $('#header').removeClass('swag-style');

                }
```

The above code means `.swag-style` class gets added after the first click triggers a scroll that meets the above condition. That in turn causes the height to change.  Subsequent clicks will find the correct height in place.

*I solved the problem by adding the line below which adds the class `.swag-style` immediately after the click, that way the correct height will be in place before the click-triggered scroll happens.*

```
$('#header, #search-box').addClass('swag-style');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `#header` doesn't have the class swag-style in the beginning so `$("#header.swag-style").height()` is null.

Try to use `$("#header").height()` instead of `$("#header.swag-style").height()`

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - $("#header").height(),
  }, 800, function(){
     return false;

   window.location.hash = newHash;

  });
```

Comment: Sorry, that did not do it for me.